What assumptions need to be validated for a GLM/GMM with a Gamma distribution?
I want to determine the effect of different attributes (sex, age...) on the rate of nest building in birds. My response variable is continuous and strictly greater than 0.
So I wanted to answer this question by performing a GLMM gamma :
"modele_gamma <- glmer(Common_Building_Rate ~ Sex + scale(MinAge, center = T, scale = T) + scale(Kinship, center = T, scale = T) + Periode + scale(MinAge, center = T, scale = T):Sex + Sex:Periode +(1|Col) + (1|Saison) + (1|Observer) + (1|Ring_ID), family=Gamma(link = log), data = Building_Without_0)"
On the other hand, by checking the normality and homoscedasticity of the model, here's what I get:

From what I've read, the fact that the distribution of the model's residuals doesn't follow a normal distribution for the gamma distribution makes sense? What about homoscedasticity? (because this is not respected at all in my case).
